# Kill / Stop an application with Java Code

Tags: java, process, kill

Is it possible to stop an application in windows using java code ? 
I'd like to create a program which is like a shortcut to stop an application on my pc. Is it possible using ProcessBuilder ? Thank you

Comment: I've done it in the past by wrapping calls to the *pskill* Windows util (don't know if that one is still around) using *Runtime.exec*.  However I don't know which guaranteed the OS makes regarding *pskill*.  AFAICT on Windows it's much more different than on Un*x.  On Un*x issuing a *SIGKILL* means that the program **must** exit immediately and that all its resources **must** be given back to the OS (it's the theory and it works quite well in practice).

Comment: TerminateProcess and NtTerminateProcess are analogous to sending SIGKILL in NT - that is, it requests the OS to terminate the process "immediately," although (for Linux and Windows, and probably most *nix) this may be deferred due to the process accessing certain system resources (such as an IO call that never returns).  The analogue to SIGTERM in Windows is to send a WM_CLOSE window message to a window of the application, unless the application is a service.  In that case, use ControlService with dwControl = SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP.

Answer (score 3):

Plain Java, without native access?  No.

ProcessBuilder lets you control processes that you started from within the Java application, but it doesn't give you control to processes that were started by other processes.

As per user988052's comment, you can use `pskill` from the [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) to accomplish this through `Runtime.exec`.  `pskill` uses the [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function call.  You can also call this function with JNI (or some other native caller, like JNA, NLink, etc.), but you'll need to obtain a handle to the process via the [OpenProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) function call.

Comment: If you use OpenProcess, be sure you request PROCESS_TERMINATE (0x0001) in dwDesiredAccess.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to stop an application in windows using java code ? ... Is it possible using ProcessBuilder ?

Only if you launched the application from the same Java application that you are trying to fill it from.

Other than that, you need to resort to running a Windows-specific command to do the killing ... or something based on JNI to make native Windows library calls.

The other complications are that you may not be able to kill certain processes due to permissions issues, and some process may refuse to be killed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the JRE does not provide an API for system processes.  `ProcessBuilder` can *create* system processes, but it cannot provide you with a `Process` object for a process created outside the JVM.  I believe that is a philosophical decision on the part of the Java folks, to avoid certain OS-specific tasks where possible.  You might think that every OS has pids, or that they all have some kind of kill message, but Java runs on lots of OSes, some of them quite strange.

You could make native code to do it and wrap that with JNI, but that would be wasteful.  As Mr 988052 says, I suggest you execute a system-specific command through `Runtime.exec` or `ProcessBuilder`.  You would need to decide which OSes you want to support, and be sure to get the commands (and the OS-detection code) right for each one.